# Nativescript - custom css for Iphone 10

Tags: nativescript

The question in general is about (or it's possible ?) to use any snippet or plugin to target iphone 10 ?
My app works well for any iphone except iphone 10.
I'm looking any way to use custom css for this device. Sorry, no code attached,as my question is very general.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [this](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-support-multiple-screen-sizes-in-your-nativescript-app-typescript-and-angluar/273/3) post on the NativeScript forum. The topic is more about screensizes but should help with your problem. The [linked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-platform-css) plugin allows you to write platform (and for iOS phone) specific css.

If you decide to use the plugin: make sure you read everything about the plugin, there are some tricky situations that can occur.